# Example of a non-linear map $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ that preserves the scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

What is an example of a non-linear map $f:\Bbb R^2 \to\Bbb R$ such that $f(a(x,y))=af((x,y))$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "what is an example of a *nonlinear* map..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, can it be $F(x,y)=\sqrt[2n+1]{x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}}$, with $n\in\mathbb N/\{0\}$? (I assume $a$ is real...)

Comment: What about the one you gave earlier $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? I think that one works as well?

Comment: Nope as the square root gives you the absolute value of $a$ and not, strictly, $a$

Comment: Ok if you take n to be 1, and x1,x2,y1,y2 to be 1, then F((x1,y1))+F((x2,y2)) seems to be the same as F((x1+y1,x2+y2)

Comment: Yes but it shall hold for EVERY pair of point you choose

Comment: For n=1 you mean $F(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$?

Comment: Yes I calculated using online calculator.

Comment: Actually I had to remove $n=0$ as in that case the application is linear and not nonlinear 